# Salesforce community with URI

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

I haven't been able to find any docs online so I don't know if this is actually achievable.

Currently where I work we have a couple different landing pages, they are built in Wordpress and each of our sales people have one page of each landing pages. This means that for each landing page we have as many pages as salespersons. So I am trying to avoid this, I was thinking in using Laravel as i can easily get the route and use the same controller to display the info of the page like:

`Route::get(/{name}, controllername)`

My question is, is it possible with Salesforce to set up a site or community and using URI to display an specific page?

so if my domain is like test.com: and someone goes to

test.com/sydney

or

test.com/melbourne

I can display the same page but treat sydney or melbourne as my parameter?

or the only way that i can achieve this is by doing

test.com/visualforpage?city=sydney

Answer (score 0):

If you're building in Site.com, you can build a single template that is the basis for each "City" page. This assumes that you have a specific set of defined cities, and you would create a page for each based on your single template.

[Creating Site.com Page Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_page_master_create.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, but this way i will still need to create a page per city? because that is what I am trying to avoid. Thanks